# CSS Transition on hover:after

Tags: css

I have a code:

```css
ul {
  width: 160px;
}

ul li a {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

ul li  a {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        transition: all .3s ease-in;
   }

    ul li a:hover:after {
        content: '';
        width: 26px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: #10c3a2;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Item</a>
  <li><a href="">Item</a>
</ul>
```

Why the transition is not working on hover:after? I tried to put the transition on hover and in after but it's not working. How I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Because your pseudo element only exists when the link is hovered, as soon as that is not the case any more, it is immediately gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add this in `:after`

```css
ul {
  width: 160px;
}

ul li a {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

ul li  a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #10c3a2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

ul li a:hover:after {
  width: 26px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Item</a>
  <li><a href="">Item</a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties like `content` and `display` cannot be transitioned. Those should be declared in the base state, and then you can transition numeric properties, such as `opacity`, if you want it to fade in/out.

p/s: Use `::after` instead of `:after`. The latter is an old syntax.

```css
ul {
  width: 160px;
}

ul li a {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

ul li a::after {
  content: '';
  width: 26px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #10c3a2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

ul li a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
</ul>
```